# Gradlew init - no such file or directory

Tags: java, docker, gradle, dockerfile, gradlew

I'm trying to build my Java app using Docker file. There is a step that does next:

```
RUN ./gradlew init
```

There is such file gradlew.bat for my Windows machine. And if I execute it from PowerShell all goes well.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine as builder

WORKDIR home

#get gradle wrapper
ADD gradle /home/gradle
COPY gradlew ./
COPY gradlew.bat ./
RUN ./gradlew init <--- gives error
```

Running command from Docker file give me next error. What I do wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well it's not a problem in your dockerfile. I created dummy scripts to mimic your build steps, they go through fine:

```
$ docker build .
.
.
Step 6 : RUN ./gradlew init
 ---> Running in 0228bf5340d9
This is dummy output: init
 ---> 7835d2972bf9
Removing intermediate container 0228bf5340d9
Successfully built 7835d2972bf9
```

Apparently a problem with `gradlew` instead, also reported [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/443304/running-gradlew-produces-no-such-file-or-directory)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should check is the line breaking of your gradlew file. Changing it to LF will solve your issue.